# Azure site created from PowerShell in C# not being found

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

I'm having a strange problem. I'm trying to create an Azure site by running PowerShell script from my C# code. I open the script file, modify it to insert the necessary data, save it and then run it. This is the script:

```
$azureUserName = "myusername"
$azurePass = "mypass"
$siteName = "myurl"
$clientID = "*******"
$clientSecret = "********"
$subscriptionID = "*******"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $azurePass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureUserName, $securePassword)
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred 
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionID
New-AzureWebsite $siteName | Set-AzureWebsite -WebSocketsEnabled $true -AppSettings @{"ClientID"=$clientID;"ClientSecret"=$clientSecret}


#Get the website's propeties.
$website = Get-AzureWebSite -Name $siteName
$siteProperties = $website.SiteProperties.Properties

#extract url, username and password
$url = ($siteProperties | ?{ $_.Name -eq "RepositoryURI" }).Value.ToString() + "/MsDeploy.axd"
$userName = ($siteProperties | ?{ $_.Name -eq "PublishingUsername" }).Value
$pw = ($siteProperties | ?{ $_.Name -eq "PublishingPassword" }).Value

#build the command line argument for the deploy.cmd :
$argFormat = ' /y /m:"{0}" -allowUntrusted /u:"{1}" /p:"{2}" /a:Basic'
$arguments = [string]::Format($argFormat, $url, $userName, $pw)
```

The thing is. If I modify the data manually and then run it from PowerShell ISE the site is being created and is running perfectly. If I modify the data from code and run it, the site is also being created and seems to be working ok but when I try navigating to it it is not being found.
This is how I run the script:

```
using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{                   
String file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(filesPath, "CreateAzureSite.ps1"),Encoding.UTF8);
powershell.AddScript(file);
Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Curious - why are you trying to run powerShell inside c#?  Why not just use Azure's Management REST API?

Comment: Don't want to play with the whole certificate stuff. Besides, creating a site from PowerShell is easier as the documentation is better. Of course I can do it with the .NET libraries. The question however is, what might cause such effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .NET management libraries:

- Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.management.websites(v=azure.11).aspx
- Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites/4.4.1-prerelease